# Can I play against or with Xbox 360 players through my Xbox One?

Tags: xbox-360, xbox-one, xbox-network, backwards-compatibility

Is it possible to play against and with Xbox 360 players through my Xbox One?

Comment: See http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/11084/101016

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This depends on two main factors:

**I am running an Xbox One version of the game on my Xbox One**

No, in almost every game the multiplayer functionality does not support cross-platform features.

There are very few exceptions, such as World of Tanks allowing for cross-platform gaming.

**I am running an Xbox 360 version of the game on my Xbox One**

Yes.  This is through the backward compatibility feature.  More details can be found from the official site here:

[Xbox One Backward Compatibility](http://www.xbox.com/en-us/xbox-one/backward-compatibility)

Here is a relevant question from the [feature's FAQ](http://support.xbox.com/en-us/xbox-one/system/compatibility-with-xbox-360-faq#af9a8c98cbd64a32a45b4ca16e56060a):

> **Can I do multiplayer gaming with friends who are playing the game on Xbox 360 or Xbox One?**
>
> Yes. For games that offer multiplayer gaming, you'll be able to play with others who own the title on Xbox 360.

The list of supported games can be found on the official site here:

[Supported Games](http://www.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-one/backward-compatibility/available-games)

Comment: To clarify, when you run the 360 game on your xbox one, you are running an xbox 360 emulator. You are still accessing the 360 server for multiplayer, so actual console does not make a difference.

Comment: Your statement regarding cross-platform is wrong, there are games who support cross-platform play.

Comment: @Eric - Which games?

Comment: I have adjusted the answer, accordingly.  I will do some more research, but currently only seeing an exception to the current standard.  I don't think it would be hard to accommodate a very short list into this answer.

Comment: @CamelCase see my reply on meta. You are right, accommodating a short list is no trouble at all. What I worry about is the need to lengthen the list eventually.

Comment: @eric - at the moment, this pretty much applies to all games minus a handful.  When this is no longer the case then the answer will need changes.  Of the hundreds of games released on Xbox so far, I doubt anything will change for these games.  Any changes will probably come in the form of new games.

Comment: @CamelCase, given that they are at the point where they need to remove content from the game to run it on the Xbox 360, I'm doubtful this will be a big issue, in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, my friend has xbox one and I have xbox 360. I just played Samurai Shodown II and NBA JAMs On Fire Edition with him on Live.